# Error in designing a RESTful API With Node and Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am following [this tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WDpeb6IrKuX) to teach myself how to connect to postgres through node.  Everything works well up until testing the first request, which returns an error.

Test the request out in the browser - http://localhost:3000/api/puppies:

I have followed directions precisely.  What may have gone wrong?

```
404

Error: Not Found
    at /Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

---

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Paste the code for the function around line 30 for this file on your system /Users/alexander/node-postgres-promises/app.js. we need to see what your routes look like.

Comment: Okay I've added that file below the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing the right thing. You're trying to GET http://localhost:3000/api/puppies and there's no route for that, but you do have a catch-all handler here

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

That catches *everything* else and throws an error with the text "Not Found".

Comment: Okay. what would I need to do for the browser to retrieve this : `{
  status: "success",
  data: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tyler",
    breed: "Shih-tzu",
    age: 3,
    sex: "M"
  },
  message: "Retrieved ONE puppy"
}` ?  As per the tutorial? I am confused

Comment: I would need to see the routes defined here `
var routes = require('./routes/index');`

Comment: Thanks ,I've added that file as well

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's a lot of stuff in that tutorial that doesn't line up with what you have in your project so you should just spend some time doing what it says in the tutorial

Comment: I've copied everything verbatim